# Need to update a query from dropdown section

Tags: javascript, php

Mates,
 I have this dropdown menu and I need to update a section and the database with a radio button whenever any user clicks it. I' m not sure how can I achieve it.

My dropdown looks like this

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropMenu"><span class="col_blue">Welcome:</span> <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">

  <form class="form">
    <div class="switch-field">
      <div class="switch-title">Make Resume Public?</div>
      <input type="radio" id="switch_left" name="switch_2" value="yes" checked/>
      <label for="switch_left">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" id="switch_right" name="switch_2" value="no" />
      <label for="switch_right">No</label>
    </div>
</form>  

    <?php
    $switch_2 = $_POST['switch_2'];

    $qry = "UPDATE resumes SET public = :public WHERE memberID = :memberID";
    $stm = $db->prepare($qry);
    $stm->bindParam(':public', $switch_2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stm->bindParam(':memberID', $uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stm->execute();
    ?>

    <?php
    $stmt = $db->prepare("select * from jobs where jobposterID = '".$_SESSION['memberID']."'");
            $stmt->execute();
            $jobs = $stmt->rowCount();    
    ?>              
    <a href="<?php echo DIR; ?>my-jobs.php"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i> MY JOBS (<?php echo $jobs; ?>) </a>
    <a href="<?php echo DIR; ?>applied-jobs.php"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> APPLIED JOBS </a>     
    <a href="<?php echo DIR; ?>viewed-jobs.php"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> VIEWED JOBS </a>
    <a href="<?php echo DIR; ?>logout.php"><i class="fa  fa-power-off"></i> LOGOUT </a>
  </div>
  </div>
```

and i needed this portion to be updated whichever gets clicked should update database and remain selected

```
<form class="form">
    <div class="switch-field">
      <div class="switch-title">Make Resume Public?</div>
      <input type="radio" id="switch_left" name="switch_2" value="yes" checked/>
      <label for="switch_left">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" id="switch_right" name="switch_2" value="no" />
      <label for="switch_right">No</label>
    </div>
</form>  

    <?php
    $switch_2 = $_POST['switch_2'];

    $qry = "UPDATE resumes SET public = :public WHERE memberID = :memberID";
    $stm = $db->prepare($qry);
    $stm->bindParam(':public', $switch_2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stm->bindParam(':memberID', $uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stm->execute();
    ?>
```

Appreciate your help and time.

Comment: Is there any javascript you wrote to get dropdown value change?

Comment: no no i guess javascript is not required i just need it to update database and which result is stored in db should show selected

Comment: So where is your query which is getting value from database of radio ? And I can't see any dropdown there. I think it's radio button you want it to be selected. Right?

Comment: yes mate just the radio form portion is what i need help with keeping result selected and with my sql query it should update the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are able to update the database.

**Here is the code to get the radio button selected**

```
        <?php
        $switch_2 = $_POST['switch_2'];

        $qry = "UPDATE resumes SET public = :public WHERE memberID = :memberID";
        $stm = $db->prepare($qry);
        $stm->bindParam(':public', $switch_2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stm->bindParam(':memberID', $uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stm->execute();
        ?>

        <?php
        $stmt = $db->prepare("select * from jobs where jobposterID = '".$_SESSION['memberID']."'");
                $stmt->execute();
                $jobs = $stmt->rowCount();    
        ?>              
        <a href="<?php echo DIR; ?>my-jobs.php"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i> MY JOBS (<?php echo $jobs; ?>) </a>
        <a href="<?php echo DIR; ?>applied-jobs.php"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> APPLIED JOBS </a>     
        <a href="<?php echo DIR; ?>viewed-jobs.php"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> VIEWED JOBS </a>
        <a href="<?php echo DIR; ?>logout.php"><i class="fa  fa-power-off"></i> LOGOUT </a>
      </div>
      </div>
    <form class="form" id="form_abc" action="">
        <div class="switch-field">
          <div class="switch-title">Make Resume Public?</div>

          <!-- Here you need to get the public field from database on load -->
          <input type="radio" id="switch" name="switch_2" value="yes" <?php echo ($public =='Yes') ? 'checked' : ''; ?>/>

          <label for="switch_left">Yes</label>

          <!-- Here you need to get the public field from database on load -->
          <input type="radio" id="switch" name="switch_2" value="no" <?php echo ($public =='No') ? 'checked' : ''; ?> />
          <label for="switch_right">No</label>
        </div>
    </form>  

<Script>
$("#switch").on('click',function(){
// see is this alert comes?
alert('Its working');
$("#form_abc").submit();
});
</Script>
```

Comment: mate no i have no idea how to get it to update the database with this form inside this menu. if it was elsewhere i know how to but i am not getting idea how to update the database here

Comment: Trace it out buddy step by step! put alert in jquery code and so on.

Comment: is it not updating because its a include file as menu.php ??

Comment: fixed it i created external file to update it. thanks alot appreciate your time and help

Comment: Anytime buddy! @johrampong